# After rebooting, Windows on a Google Cloud Platform VM got stuck on choosing a keyboard layout / language

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google

I have access to the cloud shell of the VM in GCP (Google Cloud Platform). And I can monitor the state of the VM, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Google Cloud Platform screenshot]

However, until the system boots up, I can't connect to it. How do I start Windows to get RDP working?